# Android : Decrement a variable daily

Tags: android, variables, sharedpreferences

Heyyy, I know how to save variables and other data in SharedPreferences, but I like to know how it would be possible to decrement a variable daily.

Already this var (int) will be in the Shared Preferences, and every day we decrements of -1.

How could I decrement, knowing that the user does not necessarily open the app every day for example?

Have a good day :)

Comment: Why not just save an initial date to `SharedPreferences`, and then figure how many days it's been since then whenever you need to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several choices:

1. Every time your app starts, load the value from Shared Preferences and decrement it by the number of days which have passed.
2. Write a service which decrements the values every day.
3. Write a `BroadcastReceiver` which starts when the date changes.

Answer (score 1):

Save the original date, when the application is opened check for current date and you know what your variable should be :)

Comment: yeah that's a good solution, but if users don't run app for a day, app will don't decrement :(

Comment: Thanks all for your responses and your time, you are awesome !!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to decrement the variable on Daily Basis then

1. Implement a **BroadcastReceiver** and declare it in **AndroidManifest.xml** with action **android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED**. This would run the BroadcastReceiver once in a day when the date is changed.
2. In **onReceive()** method you can place code (validations) and persist results into **SharedPrefs**.

**Note:** 
 1. Service would incur huge running cost.
 2. Activity would run the same code everytime it opens but BroadCast would run it once a day in a clean and independent fashion.

You might need a Broadcast action `BOOT_COMPLETED` as if the device is turned on (reboot).

Answer (score 0):

I think using `JobScheduler` would be a nice way to implement this. It's available from API 21 and allows the app to execute actions under certain circumstances, even if it's not open. [Here's](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html) the official doc, and a nice tutorial [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html).